# Rendering a redux component with and without children

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've noticed that children nodes of a Redux container can automatically get passed as props to the wrapped component:

```
<Container>
  Child Text
</Container>
```

Container.js:

```
const Container = connect()(Component)
```

Component.js:

```
const Component = ({ children }) => {
  if (children) {
    return (
      <p>
        {children}
      </p>
    )
  }

  return (
      <p>
        No Child Text
      </p>
  )
}

Component.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}
```

If I now render:

```
<Container>
    Child Text
</Container>
<Container/>
```

I get a warning for `<Container/>`:

```
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop 'children' was not specified in 'Component'
```

I'm wondering how to avoid this warning whilst being able to render both variations of my component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `.isRequired`

from

```
Component.propTypes = {
   children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}
```

You basically told the container that `children` prop will be a required one, so React warns you if it's missing.